# how to prepare dataframe for discrete choice experiment with opt-out option

Tags: r, dataframe, nested, linear-regression, mlogit

please am very new in r statistics so any help will be appreciated.
I conducted a discrete choice experiment that has 2 alternatives (A and B) with an opt-out option (C), each alternative have 6 attributes with 2 levels. I have 869 respondents. I used the dummy code 1 for the 1st level and 0 for the second level
When I tried to run the analysis using the nested logit model, it came up with the issue of singularity, so I think there is something wrong with my dataframe.

My question is this, can anyone tell or show me how to prepare the data for multinomial logit regression analysis in R?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What function do you plan to use for model fitting?

Comment: Hello MrFlick, thanks for your response. I have tried severally to post a sample but all to no avail.